# Invocation Target Exception while invoking Firefox webdriver

Tags: selenium

In Eclipse, when i try to invoke the Firefox web driver i am getting the following exception

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.cisco.nm.crostest.aidan.TestExecutor.callExecute(TestExecutor.java:740)
at com.cisco.nm.crostest.aidan.TestExecutor.testLms(TestExecutor.java:909)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:164)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:130)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:120)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:230)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:225)
at org.junit.internal.runners.OldTestClassRunner.run(OldTestClassRunner.java:76)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredElementNSImpl.getTextContent()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.FileExtension.readIdFromInstallRdf(FileExtension.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.FileExtension.writeTo(FileExtension.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ClasspathExtension.writeTo(ClasspathExtension.java:63)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.installExtensions(FirefoxProfile.java:465)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.layoutOnDisk(FirefoxProfile.java:443)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:77)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:244)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:110)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:190)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:179)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:92)
    at com.cisco.nm.crostest.ipcenter.scripts.IPCmCreate.execute(IPCmCreate.java:439)
    ... 25 more
```

The code i use is

```
    Connection oracleCon = oracleUtils.getOracleConnection();
    System.out.println("check1");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    status_flag = CreateTicket(driver,oracleCon,xmlFileName,TcParam);
```

Comment: you give us all this information, yet no actual code.. you say "the code you use", but it doesn't even look like it got to the second line `System.out.println("check1");` because i'm not even seeing "check1" in that console.   Any other information you can give?

Comment: What version of Firefox? What version of Selenium?

Comment: 1. I got into second line. check 1 was printed. i dint copy it here. after printing 'check' this error is coming. Instead of FirefoxDriver if i try with InternetExplorerDriver the code is working fine. But i want my script to run in firefox

Comment: Firefox version is 16.0.1... Selenium version is 2.28.0

Answer (score 0):

Updating java 1.7-minor version worked for me.